# Android android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file

Tags: android, sqlite, google-analytics

In my android app, there are two processes, let's say process A and B

It is funny that if process A tries to access the sqlite database, everything is fine.
However, if process B does so, following exception will be shown

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file:
>   BEGIN EXCLUSIVE;

FYI, actually not my app tries to use SQLite database. Instead, I use Google Analytics to track users and it uses SQLite database.

Why does this happen? Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually what you are using is `Transaction`.and when transaction is in progress no other process can access the database.

I think that is why you are getting this exception

Sometimes it happens

1. when `beginTransaction` is called on a not-open database connection.
2. when SQL statements contain syntax errors

Comment: But as I mentioned, Google Analytics uses the sqlite database and invoke the exception. Even I call beginTransaction, I should only lock my database instead of the Analytics one.

Comment: @Bear it seems your google Analytics is taking exclusive control on your database and not letting your request to get conmpleted.

Answer (score 2):

- You have to `close` the connection with the database of **process A** first before you start using database with **process B**.
- This will solve your `concurrency`.
- we Use `db.close();`

I hope this might be your problem.

Answer (score 1):

> if process A tries to access the sqlite database, everything is fine.
>   However, if process B does so, following exception will be shown

Sqlite will only open databases from your applications database directory.

```
DB_PATH = "/data/data/"+ context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
```

In your case Database is present in Process A directory so it can access it.But Process B can not read database from Process A directory.

What you can do is copy that database file in Process B directory by giving above path.

Comment: can getApplicationContext help?

Comment: what you mean by process A and Process B are they separate projects? It would be helpful if you share your source code here.